# Nested Stack Views: Child Stack View is not inside its parent stack view when attaching it programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to implement nested stack views in which one stack view is inside another stack view. I've based my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463021/programmatically-add-subviews-to-a-uistackview). My current code is here below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var verticalStackView: UIStackView!
let blueImageView = UIImageView()
blueImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
blueImageView.image = UIImage(named: "just some image")
blueImageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.height.width.equalTo(34)
}

let greenImageView = UIImageView()
greenImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
greenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "just some image")
// This is just from SnapKit
greenImageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.height.width.equalTo(34)
}

let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal
stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing
stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
stackView.spacing = 16.0
stackView.addArrangedSubview(blueImageView)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(greenImageView)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
// This is just from SnapKit
verticalStackView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.height.equalTo(70)
}
verticalStackView.addSubview(stackView)
```

When I tried running it looks this way.

[image: Just the image]

As you can see, the sub stack view `stackView` is below the parent stack view (`verticalStackView`) in the hierarchy. But the positioning is off.

I'm quite new with Swift, AutoLayout and StackViews. Anyone that can help point out what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out the solution after some reading..

```
@IBOutlet weak var verticalStackView: UIStackView!
let blueImageView = UIImageView()
blueImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
blueImageView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowCheckGreen")
blueImageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.height.width.equalTo(34)
}

let greenImageView = UIImageView()
greenImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
greenImageView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowCheckGreen")
greenImageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.height.width.equalTo(34)
}

let firstLineStackView = UIStackView()
firstLineStackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal
firstLineStackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.Fill
firstLineStackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
firstLineStackView.spacing = 8.0

firstLineStackView.addArrangedSubview(blueImageView)
firstLineStackView.addArrangedSubview(greenImageView)
firstLineStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

let redImageView = UIImageView()
redImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
redImageView.image = UIImage(named: "buttonFollowCheckGreen")
redImageView.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
  make.height.width.equalTo(34)
}

verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(firstLineStackView)
```

I just had to use `addArrangedSubview` instead of `addSubview` and let Auto layout do the rest.  Just to fix the positioning and size of the image views, I've also modified the `alignment` of the verticalStackView from `fill` to `leading`.

Answer (score 0):

greenImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34).isActive = true
greenImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34).isActive = true

and it will be solved